# Cycles: Will fire and smoke on GPU be supported in 2.75?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Will fire and smoke on GPU be supported in 2.75?
Are there any infos about the roadmap regarding this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Blender development and not about using Blender

Comment: For future reference, the [release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.75/Cycles) and [release cycle](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Projects#2.7x_release_cycle) pages will list all features in the newest release and the targets for the next release. Note that the release notes are (mostly) updated as features are added, so you can see what is in development builds so far. For instance, the [2.76 release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76) already have a few additions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the Blender development roadmap and not about using Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.77 will support GPU rendering of Fire & Smoke :
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/Cycles

## Cycles Rendering

- Smoke/Fire and Point Density support on GPU.

In previous versions there is no support for fire and smoke on Cycles GPU, it just renders invisible or black .

Comment: Yes it fully supports smoke&fire. You can download the test build and see for yourself. Then you can write this answer for sure without speculations.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying, didn't have time yet to test it myself, that why the speculations.

Answer (score 3):

No.

I found that if you want a fast facsimile is to use OpenGL render (not in the render menu, rather a the top of the interface).  I rendered 100 frames in about a minute on a black background then "add" layer composition to the GPU smokeless animation.  Looks really good.