# After configuring the domain shader I do not see smoke simulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, smoke-simulation

I'm learning to work with the fire and render it in Cycles. After setting up the domain shader (to make it invisible), I see the mesh-emitter without fire.

[image]

What is my mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you do a quick test using "Quick Smoke" ... you can follow the instruction here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18599/smoke-domain-object-is-black?rq=1

Comment: Switch to CPU rendering, density is not supported on GPU.

Comment: @hawkenfox Yes, I originally created this scene using the Quick Smoke

Comment: @Jerryno I see ... And it is possible to render the fire and smoke in the Cycles on the GPU?

Comment: @MrZak Thank you very much, I'll try this method, is it suitable for rendering on the GPU?

Comment: It may be that not everything. You can search for release notes, something like links here- http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33253/cycles-will-fire-and-smoke-on-gpu-be-supported-in-2-75.

Comment: I think @MrZak nailed it, `density` should definitely **not** be capitalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this smoke setup the smoke and fire won't be rendered because:

1. **Attribute** node which provides information for shaders has property typed incorrect, it should be `density`.
2. There isn't any **Attribute** with property for flame.

To fix that:

- either use Quick Smoke operator from 3DView header > *Object* > *Quick Effects* which will setup objects and materials automatically. You can choose what type of smoke sim you'd like to in operator's options in the Last Operator Panel (in the *Toolshelf*). The materials will be setup appropriately:

  [image: quick smoe options]
- Automatic setup may be not desired if there is domain / flow already created (you could link materials though from objects created with Quick Smoke to your main ones). So it's possible to correct spelling of the property manually and add one more **Attribute** node which will be connected to the node tree via one more **Add** node.

See related question: [Rendering Smoke in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/rendering-smoke-in-cycles/24424#24424)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! It looks like the smoke simulation may be rendered in cycles on the GPU? That's great! I also added some nodes to adjust the smoke and fire (http://postimg.org/image/6c4xn1jkd/), using this tutorial: https://youtu.be/oSiV5gg_lCs Thank you!

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Glad it worked for you. As for GPU, I think it's [supported in 2.77](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33253/cycles-will-fire-and-smoke-on-gpu-be-supported-in-2-75), though in wiki it's [stated otherwise](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/volume.html#limitations). Unfortunately I can't make any tests.

Comment: Smoke rendering is supported in GPU starting with version 2.77